# Get Id from Linear Layout Dynamically on click Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have 4 LinearLayout in my activity i want to get the id of clicked layout how can i get it ??![enter image description here][1]

Url of view image: http://postimg.org/image/uq4hnmlkn/

LinearLayout lt = new LinearLayout(null) ;

```
    lt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(v.getId()), 
                           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```

Comment: You wrote it in your code. v.getId(). I dont understand question.

Comment: kindly view the image i linked i have 3 linear layout and when i clicked on it i need id of that layout

Comment: Register OnClickListener for each of them not for parent layout.

Comment: I want to register OnClickListner for parent layout and want to get id of that particular layout how i can do it

Comment: IMHO this is impossible. OnClickListener callback is called when registred view is clicked. I guess lt is green area at your picture. It listen on click on this area not on buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

**1.** Xml File (activity_main.xml)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/lnrMain"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center"/>
```

**2.** Java File (MainActivity.java)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private LinearLayout lnrMain;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lnrMain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lnrMain);
    for (int i=1;i<5;i++){
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        layout.setId(i);
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("Linear Layout "+i);
        textView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        layout.addView(textView);
        layout.setTag(i);
        layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Linear Layout "+view.getTag()+" Is Clicked...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        lnrMain.addView(layout);
    }
  }
}
```